# Conduit Exception

Tags: haskell, conduit

I couldn't figure out how to make `sourceDirectory` and `catchC` work.

```
src = (sourceDirectory "/does/not/exist/input.txt" $$ C.print) `catchC` \e ->
    yield (pack $ "Could not read input file: " ++ show (e :: IOException))
```

The idea is that I use sourceDirectory to walk a directory tree and in case of failure I want the program to continue and not stop.

Comment: What is module is `C` in `C.print`?

Comment: `Data.Conduit.Combinators`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `catchC` function works on individual components of a pipeline, like `sourceDirectory "somedir"` (in other words, things of type `ConduitM`). You've applied it to a *completely run* pipeline, which is just a normal action, and therefore `catchC` won't work. Your choices are:

- Apply `catchC` to the individual component, e.g. `` (sourceDirectory "foo" `catchC` handler) $$ printC ``
- Use a non-conduit-specific `catch` function (such as from [safe-exceptions](https://haskell-lang.org/library/safe-exceptions)), e.g. `` (sourceDirectory "foo" $$ printC) `catch` handler ``.

Also, a recommendation for the future: it's a good idea to include the compiler error when some code won't build.